# How to display the username in view

Tags: views, users

I'm new to Drupal 7 and I have created a content revision view. For that I have added a column of author in which I have also specified the user author relationship in view.

Problem is i am creating the content type using mobile device using web services  for this created content i have content revision view in D7 here for all the content created user name displaying as admin i,e if I check the user name column in content revision column, then it shows the same admin name for all content created through multiple users, as shown in this screen print:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In advanced section add a relationship by author like this :
[image]

Then add a field, choose User:name (the user or the author name) :
[image]

make sure that you have the relationship "author" in the field setting :
[image]

Now you should see the correct author name.

Comment: yes your right:) but thing is in my case i am creating the content using mobile device using web services so whenever i create the content via mobile device the user name is taking admin

Comment: in this case you are always logged in as admin. So please modify your question and describe how you connect to your site.

Comment: i have edited the question do u know this why?

Comment: no I don't know, but it's important to offer a clear question so maybe someone else know what you mean